# Making object calls printable

Tags: html, css, url

After making an object call, if there is a scrollbar, printing the content seems not possible. Getting rid of the scrollbar could be a solution. Here is the simplest code http://jsfiddle.net/DmF6B/50/

```
html, body, div{

   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   overflow:visible;

}
#some-object {

    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    overflow:visible;

}  
<div>

<object id="some-object" data="http://www.w3schools.com/"> </object>

</div>
```

How can i make the div expand so that the inner scroll bar wont be there? Or is there another way to print the contents ?
Here it can be seen that the Contents are not printable, @media is not working as far as i know
http://jsfiddle.net/DmF6B/50/show/

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have access to the server that is hosting the content inside the object? (ie. in this case would you have access to w3schools.com)

Comment: if you do have access to the server, you could try something like this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/hyy1f3xj/ premise is: measure internal height of object document, set object element to height of measured height. Now when you go to print, the object should wrap to multiple pages and would be printable. The reason you need access is because CORS restricts access to documents from other domains, unless specifically allowed to.

Comment: When i have Access to the Server, instead of using object calls using HTML 5 imports makes more sense. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/
However without Server (Lets say I have a.html and b.html on my Desktop) html 5 imports wont work as well. Is not there a simpler solution which will also work without Server Access ( as with a.html and b.html)